# java.io.EOFException using Soap

Tags: java, android, soap

I'm using ksoap2-android-assembly-3.4.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar in an android app

The code works ok but sometimes I get this error when I do a lot of requests

```
04-30 16:25:12.212: W/System.err(3397): java.io.EOFException
04-30 16:25:12.212: W/System.err(3397):     at libcore.io.Streams.readAsciiLine(Streams.java:203)
04-30 16:25:12.212: W/System.err(3397):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.readResponseHeaders(HttpEngine.java:560)
04-30 16:25:12.212: W/System.err(3397):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:813)
04-30 16:25:12.212: W/System.err(3397):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:274)
04-30 16:25:12.212: W/System.err(3397):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:486)
04-30 16:25:12.212: W/System.err(3397):     at org.ksoap2.transport.ServiceConnectionSE.getResponseCode(ServiceConnectionSE.java:103)
04-30 16:25:12.212: W/System.err(3397):     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:192)
04-30 16:25:12.212: W/System.err(3397):     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:118)
04-30 16:25:12.216: W/System.err(3397):     at com.coffeeandcookies.edea.app.request(app.java:142)
04-30 16:25:12.216: W/System.err(3397):     at tasks.registro.doInBackground(registro.java:43)
04-30 16:25:12.216: W/System.err(3397):     at tasks.registro.doInBackground(registro.java:1)
04-30 16:25:12.216: W/System.err(3397):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
04-30 16:25:12.216: W/System.err(3397):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
04-30 16:25:12.216: W/System.err(3397):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
04-30 16:25:12.216: W/System.err(3397):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
04-30 16:25:12.216: W/System.err(3397):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
04-30 16:25:12.216: W/System.err(3397):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
04-30 16:25:12.216: W/System.err(3397):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)


public static String request(String metodo,String sucursal, String cuenta)

{
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(app.NAMESPACE, metodo);

request.addProperty(app.param_sucursal, sucursal);
request.addProperty(app.param_cuenta, cuenta);

SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope.dotNet = true;
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(app.URL);

androidHttpTransport.debug = true;

 List<HeaderProperty> headerList = new ArrayList<HeaderProperty>();
 headerList.add(new HeaderProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + org.kobjects.base64.Base64.encode(app.user.getBytes())));

 androidHttpTransport.call(app.SOAP_ACTION, envelope, headerList);

 return androidHttpTransport.responseDump;
}
```

Thanks for the help!

maybe is a bug for the library

https://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/issues/detail?id=199

https://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/issues/detail?id=207